# Show that system of differential equations is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

"Let A be real 2 x 2 matrix. Show that if $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ belongs to $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$, then the system of differential equations: $$\begin{bmatrix} x'(t) \\ y'(t) \end{bmatrix}=A \begin{bmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} a(t) \\ b(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

is linear"

How can this question be approached?

Comment: As usual, plug the linear combination of any two solutions and show that it is also a solution...

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for answering. Could you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences